# Какие графические библиотеки и компилятор использовать для кроссплатформенности?

Tags: c, кроссплатформенность, микроконтроллеры, llvm, avr-gcc

На чистом Си без плюсов разрабатывается программа для управления устройством (микроконтроллер, плата, робот и т.д.). Компилятор avr-gcc.

Программа будет с визуальными эффектами. Чтобы проще было и нагляднее создавать эффекты, хочется создать оконный интерфейс для наглядного управления визуальными эффектами.

В каком направлении лучше развиваться? Чтобы был оконный интерфейс в стиле окон каждой ОС или в виде сайта, когда GUI организован через браузер? Когда оконные интерфейс, в программе написал код-скрипт-условия, анимировал и сохранил (прожёг программу в микроконтроллер). А если это браузер, то сохраняется файл, а потом начинаются сложности. Надо же как-то прошить программу... Т.е. получается лишний этап.

Например, написанная программа запускается на любой ОС, создаётся необходимая анимация, последовательность анимации записывается и прошивается в МК.

Какой код должен выдавать компилятор чистого Си (например, avr-gcc, gcc или mingw) для Intel, ARM, или же LLVM?

В качестве GUI рассматриваю следующие технологии: 
- GTK+
- Qt
- WxWidgets
- Tcl/Tk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По графическому фреймворку я бы проголосовал за Qt. Учтите, что Qt — это целый фреймворк, так что вам придётся его выучить и программировать в его рамках. Впрочем, он вовсе не плох.

Gtk+ и WxWidgets вроде бы не особо хороши в смысле нативного вида и поведению контролов.

Если вы пишете на правильном чистом C, без компиляторо- и платформозависимых расширений, ваш код с хорошей долей вероятности будет переносим (ну или почти переносим, за исключением небольших фрагментов, которые оформьте с `#ifdef`'ами).

Comment: Да, на "чистом" Си. Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что ненужна LLVM, достаточно будет самого gcc/mingw компилятора под каждую платформу с Qt?

Comment: @Infum: Ну да. То есть для кроссплатформенного кода по идее всё равно, gcc, clang или вообще msvc.

А где вы видите сложности с таким подходом?